# How can I translate the expression "sour grapes" into Italian?

Tags: word-usage, english-comparison, translation

From the Oxford dictionary:

> sour grapes
>
> used to refer to an attitude in which someone adopts a negative attitude to something because they cannot have it themselves:
>
> *government officials dismissed many of the complaints as sour grapes*

Is there an equivalent or similar expression in Italian?

This question has been already asked on Spanish Language & Usage and, according to the related answers, it seems that in that language the word is *envidia*, but I'm not sure that in Italian is the same. Rather, I think that one of the candidate words is *spazzatura*.

Comment: BTW, *spazzatura* would not really fit in here. Let's say, if we are talking about a Lamborghini or a Ferrari car, I wouldn't call them "trash." I'd just say that, you know... *no, I don't want such a car, because they are very long and very hard to find a parking place for.* In this case, you'd surely call my "reasons" sour grapes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Invidia** ([envy,](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/envy) a feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else’s possessions, qualities, or luck, ) might be the word you are looking for.

From [Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/invidia1/)

> **invìdia** s. f. [dal lat. invidia, der. di invĭdus: v. invido]. –
>
> 1. *Sentimento spiacevole che si prova per un bene o una qualità altrui che si vorrebbero per sé*, accompagnato spesso da avversione e rancore
>      per colui che invece possiede tale bene o qualità;

Invidia mignt cover also the case where the possession/quality does not belong to anyone specific like in "[The Fox and the Grapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_and_the_Grapes)" fable.

For your particular case, the *complaints* might be "**mossi/dettati dall'invidia**"

Comment: +1. Well, sour grapes, *uva aspra*, actually comes from that Aesop's fable, so the one-to-one answer should be simply the Italian proverb *fare come la volpe con l'uva*.

Answer (score 5):

I heard many times the expression "verde d'invidia", which would mean something like "green because of envy".

Comment: In English the phrase is "green with envy".

Answer (score 5):

Un termine consueto soprattutto a Roma e nel Lazio, e senza sinonimi. Il "rosicone". Invidioso, con rabbia e senza pace.